# Features block terraform

Tags: azure-devops, terraform

`terraform init` successfully initializes but gets stuck on terraform plan.

The error is related to the feature block. I'm unsure where to add the feature block:

> Insufficient features blocks (source code not available) At least 1 "features" blocks are required.

My configuration looks like

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.11"

  backend "azurerm" {
    features {}
   }
 }
```

I tried removing and adding features block as github page

Answer (score 52):

When you run updated version of terraform you need to define another block defined below

```
provider "azurerm" {
   features {}
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing the useful info here, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Commenting so that others can try and utilize... Thanks @Liam

Comment: For other noobs like myself - if you are explicitly aliasing all your providers (probably shouldn't be - should setup a default azurerm), but you may also get this error unless you explicitly also set `provider=azurerm.{alias}` on resources.

Answer (score 30):

An other reason for the message could be, that a named provider is in use:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  alias = "some_name" # <- here
  features {}
}
```

But not specified on the resource:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  # might this block is missing
  # -> provider = azurerm.some_name
  name     = var.rg_name
  location = var.region
}
```

Error message:

```
terraform plan
╷
│ Error: Insufficient features blocks
│
│   on <empty> line 0:
│   (source code not available)
│
│ At least 1 "features" blocks are required.
```

Comment: wow this error is absolutely a mystery! Thank you for clarifying this

Comment: took me also a while to recognize the mistake...

Comment: Saved me hours of debugging hell. Thanks!

Comment: In case of multi provider configuration, I used to get this error if I didn't use provider in every resource I create. I used provider in every resource I created to resolve this issue

Answer (score 6):

In Terraform >= 0.13, here's what a sample `versions.tf` looks like (note the provider config being in a separate block):

```
# versions.tf
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      # ...
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 0.13"
}

# This block goes outside of the required_providers block!
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please check if highlighted lines are added to your template

[image: Please check if highlighted lines are added to your template]

Comment: it not about features it's about named provider which is missing in some resources like mentioned in an answer above

Answer (score 1):

Use provider in every resource you create in case of multiple providers.
[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue because of a forgotten data source, used to fetch a resource from a provider that I was not using in the configuration - `azurerm`.

Because I had forgotten to remove this data source while refactoring, and the error is somehow misleading, took me a while to figure out where the problem was. Hopefully my answer can help someone with the same issue!